# Java >9, Cucumber and JUnit5 execution for a non spring app

Tags: java, maven, junit5, cucumber-junit

Hello dear stackoverflowers

Dealing with the Cucumber docs and a lot of "googleizing", I still stay stuck with the Maven, Java, Junit5 and Cucumber and some java modules integration (with a JDK18).

Having a very simple java desktop application (yes, I know this odd), I am trying to get my cucumber's features executed from maven (with the help of surefire.

Here is my simplified [pom.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mcgivrer/a74eec8c32dcfc52967095421b33a0fe/raw/0c70b93847b237973fc945335efb5473f7f20bd8/pom-with-junit5) file.

I think I have no more issues on the Java Module side as there is no 'illegal access" error.

But having an (I hope) clear configuration, I am not able to get the feature tests executed, nothing happened at 'surefire' side:

```
--- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ usecasetdd ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

And the Cucumber "bootstraper":

```
package com.demodemo.core.tests;

//...

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/demodemo/core/tests/features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.demodemo.core.tests")
class GameBDDTests {
}
```

And the structure of my project is as below:

[image: Project work tree structure]

Maybe I've done a basic error, but even digging the web, I've not found it... Is there a way to make that work, or no chance to achieve that?
Could you help ?

Anyway, thanks for any help you will be able to offer on this not so simple topic.

Very best regards,

McG.

Comment: Your test name is wrong https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define only the following as dependencies and don't use properties because all the dependencies of junit jupiter are defined via the bom file..

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There is no need for supplemental version properties or alike. The cucumber parts are also defined via cucumber bom.